# Show convergence in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be I.i.d. And $S_n = X_1+X_2+\dots +X_n. $Prove if $S_n/n \to 0$ in probability then $(\max_{1\leq m \leq n}S_m)/n \to 0$ in probability.

I know the idea and there is a detail I don't know how to prove. 
If |Sn-Sk|$\leq$|Sn|+|Sk| and Sn/n limits to 0 in probability, how can I prove that minP(|Sn-Sk|$\leq n\delta$)$\to $ 1 as $ n \to \infty$ ($0\leq k \leq n$)

Answer (score 0):

from the second triangular inequality, 
we have that $|S_{n}-S_{k}|\leq |S_n|+|S_k|$.
From where we can conclude that
$$
P(|S_n-S_k|>n\delta)\leq P(|S_n|+|S_k|>n\delta).
$$
Note that 
$$
  \{|S_n|+|S_k|>n\delta\}
  \subset 
  \left\{|S_n|>\frac{n\delta}{2} \right\}
  \cup
  \left\{|S_k|>\frac{n\delta}{2} \right\}.
  \qquad\qquad (1)
$$
The probability of the first set on right-hand side of (1) goes to zero when
$n$ goes to infinity by hypothesis. 
Let's suppose now that $X_i$ have finite first moment. 
In this case, for fixed $k$, the probability of the second set in (1) 
can be made small, when $n$ goes to infinity, because $P(|S_k|=+\infty)=0$. Therefore we have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\{|S_n|+|S_k|>n\delta\}) = 0.
$$
By taking complement we have what you want.

Comment: Can you explain why we can suppose Xi have finite first moment please?@Leandro

Comment: Hi Jack, I do not mean your hypothesis implies that $X_i$ have finite first moment, I just give you the argument in this case.

Comment: Oh, but what if Xi have infinite first moment? @Leandro